# Stop JQuery function inside $(document).ready function

Tags: jquery, slideshow, document-ready

I have a JQuery slider that starts automatically whenever the page loads. I also have `next` (nextSlide function) and `previous` (prevSlide function) buttons that work. What i'm trying to accomplish is this... I would like to STOP the 'autoSwitch' whenever the `$('#next').on('click',nextSlide);` or `$('#prev').on('click',prevSlide);` is activated.

In other words, autoswitch works on page load but stops as soon as user clicks the 'next' or 'previous' button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var autoSwitch = true;          // auto slider
var autoswitch_speed = 4000;    // auto slider speed

// Add initial active class
$('.slide').first().addClass('active');

// Hide slides
$('.slide').hide();

// Show first slide
$('.active').show();

// Next handler
$('#next').on('click',nextSlide);

// Previous handler
$('#prev').on('click',prevSlide);

// AutoSwitch handler
if (autoSwitch == true) {
    setInterval(nextSlide,autoswitch_speed);
}

// Switch to next slide
function nextSlide () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if ($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
        $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
}

// Switch to prev slide
function prevSlide () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if ($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
        $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
}
});
```

Comment: Set `autoSwitch` to false once a button is clicked?

Comment: I tried that...doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `setInterval` store a reference to it:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(nextSlide,autoswitch_speed);
```

Then when your direction buttons are hit clear that interval:

```
$('#next, #prev').on('click', function(){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
});
```

*(**Note:** This onclick handler must be within your `$(document).ready` function to have scope of the `intervalID` variable)*

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't think the variable needs to be defined outside the scope of `$(document).ready` because the `nextSlide()` function is also within that scope?

Comment: Thanks jcuenot...that worked! I don't fully understand it but after hours of rewrite, i'm glad to have the problem solved!

Comment: `setInterval` is a function (actually, it's `window.setInterval`) that returns a value. `window.clearInterval` is its counterpart; it takes that value and destroys the interval created by `setInterval`.